# Importar con JS puro

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que de un archivo `"index.js"` algo así:

```
function sound(src) {
sound = document.createElement("audio");
sound.src = src;
sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
sound.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(sound);
this.play = () => {
    sound.play();
}
this.stop = () => {
    sound.pause();
}
}

class Game {
    //Movimiento y composición del espacio
    Snake = [];
    director = null;
    direction = 2;
    sizeSquare = 10;
    canvas = null;
    food = null;

//Partes del juego
head = new Image();
tail = new Image();
apple = new Image();
//scream = sound();

lose = new Image();

IsLost = false;

constructor(txtButton, txtState, canvas) {
    this.txtButton = txtButton;
    this.txtState = txtState;
    this.canvas = canvas;

    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.head.src = "./img/face.png";
    this.apple.src = "./img/apple.png";
    //this.tail.src = "asja";
    this.lose.src = "./img/perdiste.jpg";
}

Init() {
    this.PrintState("Inicia");

    let square = new Object();
    square.X = 15;
    square.Y = 15;
    square.X_old = 15;
    square.Y_old = 15;
    this.Snake.push(square);

    document.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
        oGame.Printkey(e.key + " " + e.keyCode);

        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 119:
                if (oGame.direction != 3)
                    oGame.direction = 1;
                break;
            case 100:
                if (oGame.direction != 4)
                    oGame.direction = 2;
                break;
            case 115:
                if (oGame.direction != 1)
                    oGame.direction = 3;
                break;
            case 97:
                if (oGame.direction != 2)
                    oGame.direction = 4;
                break;
        }
    })

    this.director = setInterval(() => {
        this.Rules();
        if (!this.IsLost) {
            this.Next();
            this.Show();
        } else {
            // clearInterval(this.director);
            // this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            // ctx.font = "20px Tahoma";
            // ctx.textAlign = "center";
            // ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            // ctx.fillStyle = "White";
            // ctx.fillText("GAME OVER", canvas.width, canvas.height);
            clearInterval(this.director);
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.lose, 0, 0);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

.
.
.

Etc... quiero separar esto en varios archivos para no hacer este `index.js`bastante cargado.

Donde Sound sea otro archivo js, donde constructor sea otro archivo js, Init, y el resto.

Sucede que sé hacerlo por node o react, pero quería ver si hay alguna forma de hacerlo únicamente con JS, no quiero usar jQuery o algo externo. Sé que ES6 lo puede hacer, pero he intentado y no me quiere dar, siempre encuentro el error en el `import sound from './sound.js'` o en cualquiera que intente importar.

En sí este archivo tiene 345 línea de código y me falta agregarle más cosas, por lo que quería saber la forma de distribuir más este código para hacerlo más mantenible, porque por otro lado tengo un JS que maneja los css y sería otro módulo que me extendería mucho este solo archivo.

Comment: Cual es el error que encontras?

Comment: Dices: ***sé hacerlo por node o react***, y ¿en qué lo estás intentando ahora?

Comment: Maruicio, lo estoy haciendo por JS solo. Cuando me enfrenté a ReactJS me di cuenta que no sé tanto de JS y por lo tanto quería hacer el código únicamente con lo que tenga JS.

Comment: Quieres separalo para que no sea "muy pesado" (creo entender), pero harás mucha más peticiones al servidor, amén de que tendrás que llamarlos en el orden correcto...

Comment: Sí, en efecto se llaman en orden diferente. Por ejemplo, cuando pierdes, o cuando ganas y cambias de nivel, cuando deseas ver el puntaje (no hace falta tener en ejecución todo el juego si voy a ver solo una tabla con números). Por eso quiero dividirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer el uso correcto de

```
import sound from './sound.js'
```

Debes estar seguro de haber exportado dicho objeto u elemento que deseas usar. Esta es la manera más práctica y fácil de importar funciones, clases u objetos. Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: ¿Es importante especificar el .js? lo estaba haciendo como lo dices ahí y al final la función era: 
`export function sound(src){}`

Comment: En el import es necesario colocar la ruta y el nombre del archivo a importar con su debida extensión de archivo, pero para exportar no es necesario ya que solo se agrega al inicio de la función, clase o variable que deseamos exportar :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes asegurarte que en el archivo de origen especifiques los elementos que quieres que se exporten con la palabra reservada `export`

```js
// Contenido de archivo JS de origen

/*
  Funciones, clases, variables, etc. que queremos que se puedan
  consumir
*/
export const UNA_CONSTANTE = "TEXTO";

export const unaFuncion = () => {
  console.log("Llamando la primera función")
}

/*
  Incluso puedes definir un elemento para que se exporte por
  defecto
*/
export default class Persona {
  nombre = 'Maira';
}


// Esto NO se podrá consumir cuando se importe
const otraFuncion = () => {
  console.log("Llamando la segunda función")
}
```

Posteriormente en el archivo donde quieres consumir el archivo JS de origen pones:

```js
// Importanto el archivo JS de Origen

// Importando un elemento en específico
import { unaFuncion } from './origen.js';
```

Muchísima más información en:

- [Export en JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export)
- [Import en Javacript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)

Espero haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Copiaré el ejemplo y miraré bien, pues, lo he intentado así y por alguna razón en este caso, solo el sonido me termina parando toda la aplicación al intentar hacerlo así.

Comment: Ok, deberías poner lo que has adelantado junto con el error que te salta para poder ayudarte más.

Comment: Estaba mirando y este error ocurre cuando empiezo a dividir la app con el html. 

Tengo un index.html que llama el script `./js/index.js` y en este mismo nivel tengo un `./js/prueba.js` el HTML imprime el código de `index.js` pero este a su vez no me llama el `prueba.js` ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? (Recuerda que solo es desde nivel de JS)